# Translate Multiple DIV's with Google Translate Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I'm using this Google Translate JQuery script to translate my blogitems:

```
        $("#translateButton").click(function () {
        var url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_API";
        url += "&source=" + $("#sourceLang").text();
        url += "&target=" + $("#targetLang").val();
        url += "&q=" + escape($("#txtSource").text());
        $.get(url, function (data, status) {
            $("#txtTarget").val(data.data.translations[0].translatedText);
        });
    });
```

But for now i can only translate the main text and not the pagetitle. Is it possible to also translate the text inside the pagetitle DIV?

Answer (score 0):

When making a call to the Google Translate API, you can pass multiple input sources. You can find more information about the Query parameters on the APIs [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#query-parameters). With that in mind, you can have two input sources, one being the page title and the other being the main text. The result will be returned in an array following the order of the passed input sources. Here is the code snippet:

```
$("#translateButton").click(function () {
        var url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_API";
        url += "&source=" + $("#sourceLang").text();
        url += "&target=" + $("#targetLang").val();
        url += "&q=" + escape($("#txtSource").text());
        //pageTitle being the id of the div containing your page title
        url += "&q=" + escape($("#pageTitle").text());
        $.get(url, function (data, status) {
            $("#txtTarget").val(data.data.translations[0].translatedText);
            //Translated page title, which will replace the old one. 
            $("#pageTitle").val(data.data.translations[1].translatedText);
        });
    });
```